# MediaPlayer live streaming m3u8 audio error (1,-1010)

Tags: android, media-player

I use the MediaPlayer class and can play the following apple m3u8 test stream - at least the audio part ( http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8 ). But when I play the following stream I get the error "MediaPlayer(17499): Error (1,-1010)".

http://stream.rro.ch/shoutcast/radiostation2.stream/playlist.m3u8

What is error (1, -1010) and how can I play the above m3u8 stream in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that error means :

ERROR_UNSUPPORTED       = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 10, // -1010

I think its a problem when the format of the audio segments are AAC, not sure but maybe would be a clue